# How to ignore uploads folder to stop content being removed on docker server when new build is created

Tags: docker

I have created one `uploads` folder on the server and I am uploading an image in this folder using the upload functionality of PHP.

Now whenever a new build is created my newly created folder and uploaded files are removed which are inside this folder, as docker looks the repo for creating new image and not considering newly uploaded folder and files.

So, can anyone let me know what is the technique for "uploading image" functionality using PHP on docker.

Should I create a dockerignore file for informing docker to not to touch my "uploads" folder ? Will this work?

I doubt that dockeringore file will surely ignore "uploads" folder but the new image may not have my newly created folder and files inside the "uploads" folder as "uploads" folder is present in repo but my newly created folder and files are not present in repo so while creating new image docker may pick the "uploads" folder from repo and will ignore it also but will not include the newly created folder and files inside this folder. But this is my assumption.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, we were able to resolve issue by using volume. Thanks a lot for your support and sorry for the delay in reply, actually we were on other high priority issues, we tried this in last week and it worked fine. Thanks again for your kind support.

Comment: Excellent!!  Good to know

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as useful and or the right answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it is difficult to understand in which moment you are modifying your upload folder content. I will assume that this happens when your container is running and when you build again the container you lose its content.

Use volumes for that :

```
docker volume create --name data
docker run -v data:upload_folder_path_in-container
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am sorry as my explanation, as you didn't get my issue. I would like to explain it again, actually my project is having uploading functionality, whenever a user uploads files it gets uploaded in "uploads" folder. But whenever a new build is done this "uploads" folder gets empty. Will you solution work for this ?

Comment: Yes, try it. Use it as a guide  https://hub.docker.com/r/crramirez/limesurvey/ this application also have an upload folder which is needed to be saved

Comment: Thanks a lot Carlos for the reply, i was also searching from my side and found that your solution for creating volume will work for sure, now my next confusion is that after creating volume for uploads folder and uploading some pretty images on server will the contents will transferred to the next image when a new docker build is done ? If yes then do i have to do for transferring the content to the new volume in the new docker build image?

Comment: No, the content will stay on volume and won't be transferred when you build a new image. To put default content into your folder you must copy using ADD or COPY in your Dockerfile. You can of course run without volume, upload images, stop the container and make a docker commit. You changes will go into the next image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply,